# PreProcessing #define

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, string-concatenation, stringification

I am unable to understand how the preprocessor works and what does the `##` stands for in this particular example

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TEMP_KEY(type,Key) (TEMP_##type | Key)

enum TEMPKey_Type
{
    TEMP_UNKNOWN = 0,
    TEMP_SPECIAL ,
    TEMP_UNICODE
};

enum Actual_Key
{
    TEMP_RIGHT = TEMP_KEY(UNKNOWN,0x1),
    TEMP_LEFT = TEMP_KEY(SPECIAL,0x1),
    TEMP_UP = TEMP_KEY(UNICODE,0x1)
};

int main()
{
    printf("\n Value of TEMP_RIGHT : %d ",TEMP_RIGHT);
    printf("\n Value of TEMP_LEFT : %d ",TEMP_LEFT);
    printf("\n Value of TEMP_UP : %d ",TEMP_UP);

    return 0;
}
```

How does this 
`#define TEMP_KEY(type,Key) (TEMP_##type | Key)`
work or how and what exactly is `TEMP_##type` replaced by during preprocessing?

Answer (score 4):

The "##" means concatenate. Therefore `TEMP_RIGHT = TEMP_KEY(UNKNOWN,0x1)` becomes `TEMP_RIGHT = TEMP_UNKNOWN | 0x1,` ("TEMP_" and "UNKNOWN" are joined together)

Comment: *String* concatenate, that this. Also called "glue".

Answer (score 2):

`##` is the concatenation operator in #define directives.

For example, TEMP_##type for TEMP_KEY(UNICODE,0x1) call generates next code:

```
(TEMP_UNICODE | 0x1)
```

Comment: Ya got it Can you provide me any link to learn about this more

Comment: @Totie - You can read [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/). For more complex information can suggest books about c++ metaprogramming :)